# Is there a PDF/A validation function in O2S.Components.PDF4NET version 5.0.3.0?

Tags: c#, pdfa

I couldn't find a validation function in O2S.Components.PDF4NET version 5.0.3.0 which can identify if a PDF file is a valid PDF/A or not.

Is there a way to do this only using O2S.Components.PDF4NET version 5.0.3.0?

Comment: Docs rarely say what the software _cannot_ do. But if you do not find a respective class/method in the docs, then chances are high it cannot do it.

Comment: @Fildor-- Noted.

Answer (score 0):

No, O2S.Components.PDF4NET version 5.0.3.0 does not have any function which can validate a pdf file.